# how to make the result with type "float" in python ?

Tags: python

i typed a small function in python and
the code is

```
def perimeter(side1,side2,side3):
    ''' (number,number,number)->float
    return the sum of side1,side2 and side3
    >>>perimeter(1,2,3)
     6.0
    >>>perimeter(4,5,7.1)
    16.1 '''

    result = side1+side2+side3
    return result
```

but when i used it , the result was not on the shape of float , it was like the int .
how can i make it in float sort ?

( i don't know how to form a the code window here so forgive me )

Comment: to get an accurate floating point sum: `perimeter = lambda *sides: math.fsum(sides)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

typecast to float

```
def perimeter(side1, side2, side3):
    return float(side1 + side2 + side3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding integers will produce an integer. You can convert one or all of them to float, or convert the result to float:

```
return float(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if his error is still happening after `return float(side1 + side2 + side3)`, then he has to specify in the parameters that the sides are floats. `def perimeter(float(side1),float(side2),float(side3)):` Maybe that will work if nothing else is.

Comment: That's not syntactically valid.

Comment: It isn't? It just states the type that it is. Only if you pass a character it isn't valid.

Comment: Simply try it at the console.  You can't do `def f(float(x)): pass`.  Where did you see this used?

Comment: That's weird... maybe I am getting too used to Java and C++. My bad

Answer (score 1):

If you want the same precision for every result try formatting

```
 return '%.3f' % result
```

Comment: This returns a string, not a number